# unable to set $_SESSION variable with PHP variable

Tags: php

Here is where I am setting my session variables.

```
function validateUser()
{
session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
}
```

This is what print_r ($_SESSSION) echos.

```
Array ( [user] => aboshart [valid] => 1 [firstname] => [lastname] => )
```

If I echo $firstname and $lastname I get the proper values. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $_SESSION vars are usually considered trusted as it is the developer who specifies what data the value is. You are setting a $_SESSION var to an unsanitized user supplied var by not sanitizing or validating $_POST['username'] Please do so before you accidentally use $_SESSION['user'] somewhere it can cause harm like in a database query. I assume you want a secure app judging from your PHP code comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing $firstname or $lastname to the function.

```
function validateUser($firstname, $lastname)
{
    session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
    $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
}
```

$_POST and $_SESSION should be within scope but the others aren't

Comment: What he said; plus, as a rule, watch the error log for notifications and warnings.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I need. The $_POST variable is there just to demonstrate that the validateUser function is working to set session variables. I will not be using it in live code.